# Understanding Limit Points

Tags: real-analysis

I am doing some analysis and trying to understand the idea of a limit point. This is the way I am thinking of it. I would just like someone to confirm if I have the right idea, or to correct me if I am mistaken. Thanks.

The way I'm thinking of a limit point of $p$:

If there is a $q\neq p$, such that $q\in E$, then $q$ is a limit point. So, if I imagined an epsilon neighborhood, the limit points of that neighborhood, will be all points in that neighborhood besides the center, $p$, and the "boundary" points. (I don't think the "boundary" points are going to be limit points, because the definition of a neighborhood says that the metric $d(p,q)<r).$

Can someone confirm if I'm thinking about this correctly?

Edit: After consulting a few analysis books, I've changed the way I think of it as follows: A point $p$ is a limit point of $E\subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space, if the open ball with radius $\epsilon$, $\forall\epsilon>0$, centered at $p$ intersects a point in $E$ other than $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've worded it very strangely.  Try: let $X$ be a topological space (or metric space).  Then a limit point $x \in X$ of a subset $S \subset X$, is a point such that for any open neighborhood $U$ (or open ball) about $x$, there exists $y \in U \cap S, y \neq x$.